# Smooths by a 2-way factor with GAMMs

Tags: categorical-data, interaction, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm modeling an experiment with a GAMM in which there are 3 predictors: a continuous variable, `TrialNumber`; an ordered binary factor, `Condition`; and 3/4-way factor, `BlockNumber`, which should either be ordered or Helmert-coded*.

I want to include all possible combinations of their interactions into the model, and with `R`'s `mgcv` package, I've been doing something like:

```
mgcv::gam(Y ~ Condition*BlockNumber + 
              ti(TrialNumber) + 
              ti(TrialNumber, by=Condition) +
              ti(TrialNumber, by=BlockNumber))
```

But that doesn't include their three-way interaction, i.e. something like:

```
ti(TrialNumber, by=c(Condition, BlockNumber))
```

Other than creating a new factor variable that represents the interaction of `Condition` and `BlockNumber` and using *that* with `by=` (is that even Kosher, by the way?), is there anything I can do?

**Footnotes:**

* `BlockNumber` is referencing which of 3 (potentially 4) sequential blocks a response occurred in. The assumption that there will be a linear trend in the response with block progression.

Comment: What is your aim? To add separate smooth of `TrialNumber` for `Condition` nested within `BlockNumber`?

Comment: It's really hard for me to conceptualize, but I'm trying to find the GAMM equivalent of three-way interaction between 2 categorical variables and 1 continuous variable (i.e. in linear models).
To some extent, I'd like to add smooths that take into account both `Condition` and `BlockNumber` variables, so that I can see if there are any super-additive effects, for example